# Swift1.2 Xcode6.4 iOS8 コードでAutoLayoutしようとするとSIGABRTエラー

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode6, ios8

現在、Xcode6.4でiOS8 iPhoneのアプリ開発を行っています。 
StoryboardやXibは使用せず、すべてSwift1.2コードで書いています。

ファーストビューをAutoLayoutoで以下のようにしたいです。

「navigationBar」 
「UILabel」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」 
「UIImageView」

※「UILabel」から下はScrollViewにしたい 
 「UIImageView」はアスペクト比を維持したまま横幅いっぱいに表示させたい

しかし、UIImageViewにAutoLayoutを設定しようとするとエミュレータ実行時にアプリが落ちます。 
ソースはこちらです

```
class AreaSelectViewController: UIViewController {

var myImageView: UIImageView!
var infoLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "FirstView"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.initLabel()
    self.initImage()
    self.initAutolayout()

}

// ラベル生成
func initLabel(){
    infoLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(displayWidth/2-150, 80, 300, 30))

    infoLabel.text = "Labelテキスト"
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    infoLabel.textColor = btBlack
    infoLabel.font = btFontS

    infoLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(infoLabel)
}


// 画像生成
func initImage(){
    myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,70))
    myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "xxxxxx.png")

    myImageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
}


// Autolayout
func initAutolayout(){
    //myImageView
    self.myImageView.addConstraints([

        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self.myImageView,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.view,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline,
            multiplier: 1182/202,
            constant: 120
        )
    ])

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

ログには 
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 
と出ています。

Answer (score 2):

落ちることに関して言えば、

```
self.myImageView.addConstraints([
```

を

```
self.view.addConstraints([
```

にすれば落ちなくなります。

余計なお世話ですが、Constraintをあまり理解されていないようですので、一度Storyboard上でConstraintを作成してからコードに落とした方が良いんじゃないでしょうか？